# Cross-validation giving better results than separate test test

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, weka

I am using J48 in Weka.
The accuracy results of the cross-validation is about 99.9% but when I provide a separate test set the accuracy drops to about 65% or less.
So the question is why there is a big difference in accuracy? and which one we have to trust (cross-validation or providing separate test set)?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more information on the dataset and the problem. That's not a usual difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the data is collected from different sensors (accelerometer and Gyroscope) to classify human activities. If I used cross-validation in the results list shows "trees.J48" which is good and the accuracy is 99.98%.
if I provid a separate test set, the results list shows: "misc.InputMappedClassifier" I do not know why! and the accuracy is 67.37%. There is really a big difference between the two results! and why in the results list when supply a test set it shows "misc.InputMappedClassifier"? Thanks you

Comment: Based on the explanation given in the below link, you have missing values in the test set. If the data is small, you can append it into your post maybe: https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/misc/InputMappedClassifier.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i am sure there is no missing values in the test set as i collected the test data in the same environment (features and classes). But in the test set i also have the classes labelled, so maybe this cause the problem?